# ggplot clean up y axis on stacked bar plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a stacked bar plot using `ggplot` but my y axis seems incorrect.

I am using the following code:

```
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x = X__1, y = value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

I have tried `scale_y_continuous()` also but does not work.

It would be awesome if the figures can be placed inside each bar for each firm also and the dates to be plotted in order.

Any advice would be great!

EDIT: I have an updated model:

```
df$X__1
quarters <- c("Q1-16", "Q2-16", "Q3-16", "Q4-16", "Q1-17", "Q2-17", "Q3-17", "Q4-17", "Q1-18", "Q2-18", "Q3-18")
df$quarters <- as.yearqtr(quarters, format = "Q%q-%y")
#df$quarters <- as.Date(as.yearqtr(quarters, format = "Q%q-%y"))
# df$quarters <- quarters
df$X__1 <- NULL

barplot(as.matrix(df))

colnames(df)

library(tidyquant)
dat.m <- melt(df, id.vars = "quarters")
dat.m <- dat.m %>% arrange(quarters)
dat.m$value <- as.numeric(dat.m$value)
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x = quarters, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  geom_text(aes(y = value, label = value), size = 2) +
  theme_tq(base_size = 11, base_family = "")
```

DATA:

```
df <- structure(list(X__1 = c("1Q '16", "2Q '16", "3Q '16", "4Q '16", 
"1Q '17", "2Q '17", "3Q '17", "4Q '17", "1Q '18", "2Q '18", "3Q '18"
), Samsung = c(81.19, 76.74, 71.73, 76.78, 78.77, 82.86, 85.61, 
74.03, 78.56, 72.34, 73.36), Apple = c(51.63, 44.4, 43, 77.04, 
51.99, 44.31, 45.44, 73.18, 54.06, 44.72, 45.75), Huawei = c(28.86, 
30.67, 32.49, 40.8, 34.18, 35.96, 36.5, 43.89, 40.43, 49.85, 
52.22), Xiaomi = c("-", "-", "14.93", "15.75", "30.92", "21.18", 
"26.85", "28.19", "28.5", "32.83", "33.22"), Oppo = c(15.89, 
18.11, 24.59, 26.7, 30.92, 26.09, 29.45, 25.66, 28.17, 28.51, 
30.56), Vivo = c("14", "14.24", "-", "-", "25.84", "24.32", "-", 
"-", "-", "-", "-"), Others = c(156.65, 159.19, 185.5, 195.06, 
125.88, 131.87, 159.55, 162.91, 153.78, 146.1, 153.96)), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The values do not fit in the correct positions. Also I am trying to put the "Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4" on the x-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Your `value` variable is a character, and it should be numeric; try:

```
dat.m$value <- as.numeric(dat.m$value)
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x = X__1, y = value, fill=variable)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```